# split line in cpp with multiple delimiter

Tags: c++, boost, split

I want to split each line  by the appearance of  **`<=>`** or **`=>`** So I have 2 delimiters and each of them has more than one character

```
  string example="A + B => C + D";
  vector <string> leftRight;
  boost::algorithm::split_regex( leftRight, example, boost::is_any_of( " <=> +| => " ));
```

my expected result is something like this:

```
leftright[0]= A+B
leftright[1]= C+D
```

Comment: This is different I am looking for a way to split by multiple delimiter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, let's look at `boost::algorithm::split_regex`. You're doing well until the last parameter. That function expects a boost::regex as the last parameter, and `boost::is_any_of` does not provide one of those.

A reasonable regular expression for your use case would be something like this:

```
boost::regex r("(<=>)|(=>)");
```

If we put all of this together:

```
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/regex.hpp>
#include <boost/algorithm/string/regex.hpp>

int main() {
    std::string example="A + B => C + D";
    std::vector <std::string> leftRight;
    boost::regex r("(<=>)|(=>)");
    boost::algorithm::split_regex(leftRight, example, r);

    for (int i=0; i<leftRight.size(); ++i)
        std::cout << "\"" << leftRight[i] << "\"\n";
}
```

We get an output of:

```
"A + B "
" C + D"
```